# How to write custom plugins for phonegap + blackberry 10?

Tags: cordova, plugins, blackberry-10

I managed to install my phonegap/cordova app in the blackberry 10 simulator, so basically I am ready to start web app development.

However I am wondering how I could create custom phonegap plugins which can be accessed by the web app via phonegap?
I found http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_plugin-development_blackberry_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20BlackBerry, but to me it seems this information is outdated or related to older blackberry devices.

Does this java-class method still work on blackberry 10? If so, how can I access native code functions using a java plugin class?
If not, can I write a plugin using C++ code (probably using JNEXT https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/creating_extensions_for_bb10_apps.html), and is there any phonegap documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a C++ JNEXT extension, but check the WebWorks documentation first to ensure the functionality you need isn't already available:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/

There is also a collection of community extensions hosted on GitHub:

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10

We are planning an update later this year which will align WebWorks extensions with the cordova plugin model, but for now I recommend following the documentation which you linked to for creating extensions.